# TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable - python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have been reading about this error and I understand that it is because I expect a function to return a result but in reality it is not, I have reviewed my code and I do not find that it could be wrong

```
class Estudiante:
   def __init__(self):
      self.nombre = ""
      self.cedula = 0
      self.apellido = ""
      self.asignatura = ""
      self.cantidadDeNotas = 0
      self.notas = []

   @property
      def obtenerDatos(self):
         print("ingrese los datos del estudiante")
         self.cedula = int(input("Cedula del estudiante: "))
         self.nombre = input("Nombre del estudiante: ")
         self.apellido = input("Apellido del estudiante: ")
         self.asignatura = input("Asignatura: ")
         while True:
            self.cantidadDeNotas = int(input("¿cual es la cantidad de notas que desea ingresar?(más de 4): "))
            if self.cantidadDeNotas > 4:
                break
            else:
                print("ingrese una cantidad mayor a 4")
    
estudiante = Estudiante()
estudiante.obtenerDatos()
```

Comment: The error in your code is that `obtenerDatos` is decorated as a `property`, but it's implemented and called like a normal method.  Just remove the `@property`, since this function is clearly not supposed to behave like a property.

Comment: You're making us guess where the error is.  Please update the question to include the full error traceback message.

Comment: That's not the best use of `@property`. Remove that. Don't use properties as functions with side effects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you decorate a method as `@property`, it will automatically become a getter method for a property it is named after. It is then accessed not as `object.method()` but `object.method` (which will still call the same method underneath, and evaluate to its return value).

In your case, you are declaring `obtenerDatos` a property getter, but then calling `estudiante.obtenerDatos()`. This would be like calling `estudiante.obtenerDatos()()` if there were no `@property` tag - you call the method and then try to call its return value as a function.

Since the method does not return a value, this means your code tries to call None as a function.